# Evaluate Indefinite Integral

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I found an integral from the MIT Integration Bee.  The following problem was supposed to be solved within a 2 minute time limit.

$$\displaystyle\int \dfrac{\sqrt{x^3-1}}{x}\,dx$$

I understand that this problem may be solved using hyperbolic trigonometric functions, but is there a quicker solution (since you are only given 2 minutes to solve the integral)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $u^2 = x^3-1$, $2u \, du = 3x^2 \, dx$, so we have $$\int \frac{\sqrt{x^3 - 1}}{x} \, dx = \frac{1}{3} \int 3x^2 \frac{\sqrt{x^3-1}}{x^3} \, dx = \frac{2}{3} \int \frac{u^2}{u^2+1} \, du,$$ and the rest is easy.

Comment: Ohh.. the pressure, to do it in 2 mins. You made it though.

Comment: This was an excellent solution. Thank you.

Comment: @Lucian No.  My computation is correct.  The extra $u$ comes from the substitution.